# How to subscribe to Pub/Sub topics when they are created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a GCP project with various pub/sub topics and I want to have subscriptions for all of those topics and attach them automatically when they are created (my use case is that any message that is sent to any topic on GCP should be sent to the same topic on AWS via a Cloud Function).

Whats the problem here, I think you can't have a single subscription for more than one topic, and I dont know how to create subscriptions automatically when new topics are created.

I would like that, when someone creates a topic, a new subscription pointing to a "standard/fixed" CF is created automatically.

Anybody knows how to achieve this?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching I got this working by using `Eventarc` with the event type of `google.pubsub.v1.Publisher.CreateTopic`.

This way I trigger a Cloud Function every time a person creates a topic in Cloud Pub/Sub which allows me to create new subscriptions and other necessary logic.

If you are doing it like this, remember to create the event on eventarc with the `global` region.

Cheers!